# Tracking electron app uninstalls

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I'd like to log an event (ie, send it to my logging server) when a user uninstalls my electron app. Is this possible? E.g., some kind of pre-uninstall hook?

I'm using `electron-builder` with an `NSIS` windows installer and a `dmg` MacOS installer, as well as `electron-updater` for auto update.

Answer (score 3):

NSIS — please use custom macro `customUnInstall` (https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/wiki/NSIS#custom-nsis-script).

DMG — not possible, since app uninstalled by simple move to trash.